# fluent-ffmpeg and ffmpeg-concat not cutting and merging video in Docker container

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I am using [react-media-recorder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-media-recorder) to record the video on ReactJS application which further sends to my NodeJS backend to cut and contact/merge video using [fluent-ffmpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg) and [ffmpeg-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg-concat), before merging the video I am making all the uploaded video to same size `640x360`.

NodeJS code to cut the video and make the same size `640x360` before merging, also added padding to keep the consistency of video ratio.

```
const allCutVideos = await Promise.all(convertVideoList.map(async (row) => {

  return await new Promise((resolve) => {

   ffmpeg(row.uploadedFile)
    .setStartTime(row.startTime)
    .setDuration(row.endTime)
    .size("640x360")
    .autopad()
    .withAudioCodec('copy')
    .on("start", function (commandLine) {
      console.log("Spawned FFmpeg with command: " + commandLine);
    })
    .on("error", function (err) {
      resolve({ ...row, status: false, message: err.message })
    })
    .on("end", function (err) {
      if (!err) {
        resolve({ ...row, status: true });
      }
    })
    .output(row.outputPath)
    .run();

  });

}));
```

Once I get all the video(recorded video or any mp4 which are downloaded from internet) from the above promises, I am merging it using `ffmpeg-concat`, below is the code

```
const contactVideoList = allCutVideos.map(row => row.status === true ? row.outputPath : null).filter(row => row);
await ContactVideos({
  output: "/app/folder/tmp/output.mp4",
  videos: contactVideoList,
  transition: {
    name: 'directionalWipe',
    duration: 500
  }
});
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14
RUN mkdir /opt/prod_api
WORKDIR /opt/prod_api

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y ffmpeg

COPY . .

RUN chmod 777 -R /opt

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/prod_api/entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

On my local the above process working as expected (using `macOS`), I do not get any error while performing.

**When I tried the same code using `Dockerfile` I get the below problems.**

**Problem 1:** I am cutting video with `fluent-ffmpeg` which is recorded through `react-media-recorder`, I get error **`TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'width' of 'scenes[0]' as it is undefined.`**, and here is full ffmpeg command, here I am getting error while cutting and resizing video.

```
ffmpeg -ss 0 -i /opt/prod_api/assets/tmp/6b7286081d/3fb0e15881097c1aa93f8393f863e79.mp4 -y -acodec copy -filter:v scale=w='if(gt(a,1.7777777777777777),640,trunc(360*a/2)*2)':h='if(lt(a,1.7777777777777777),360,trunc(640/a/2)*2)',pad=w=640:h=360:x='if(gt(a,1.7777777777777777),0,(640-iw)/2)':y='if(lt(a,1.7777777777777777),0,(360-ih)/2)':color=black -t 12.23 /opt/prod_api/assets/tmp/6b7286081d/9b6e5551011d120289b906abd2f2b69_output.mp4
```

**Problem 2:** After uploading any `mp4` video which is download from the internet I do get another error while performing an action using `ffmpeg-concat`. **Error - `Failed to create OpenGL context. Please see https://github.com/stackgl/headless-gl#supported-platforms-and-nodejs-versions for compatibility. failed to create OpenGL context.`** (here in this case I do not get any error while performing `fluent-ffmpeg`)

Am I missing any steps in `Dockerfile`? Everything works fine in my local but getting the above problems in `Docker container`. Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.